# To many arguments for public fun Fragment.findNavController()

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.example.tender.R
import com.example.tender.databinding.FragmentAvailableTenderBinding
import com.example.tender.databinding.FragmentLoginBinding
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class AvailableTenderFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val binding = FragmentAvailableTenderBinding.inflate(inflater)

        drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout

        **val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)**

        **NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)**

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController)

        binding.root

    }
}
```

"To many arguments for public fun Fragment.findNavController():NAvcontroller defined in androidx.navigation.fragment" is showing when i hover on findnavcontroller.I am unable to resolve the error on the above bold lines.In this case what should I do?

Comment: `findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)` and `setupActionBarWithNavController` are methods you'd call in your Activity, not in a Fragment. Can you explain the setup of your app?

Comment: Thank You for answering! Ohh! yes I wrote It on wrong place, it is helpful for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Navigate to a destination documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate), the `androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController` you've imported takes no parameters (it finds the parent NavHostFragment of the current Fragment and doesn't need the ID of the NavHostFragment).

The lines you've written, namely `findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)` and `setupActionBarWithNavController()` are methods you'd call in an Activity, not in a Fragment.

Comment: If this helped answer your question, make sure to accept the answer to remove this question from the queue of unanswered questions. Best of luck going forward!

Comment: This is quite confusing, why :
`val navController = findNavController()`  
`bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)`  

Does not work inside the `onActivityCreated()` of a fragment that has a navHost?